# R Corrplot Variable Names with Integer in Leading Position

Tags: r, read.csv, r-corrplot

In my excel file, the name of two of my variables are 2B and 3B, which means doubles and triples in baseball. However, when using corrplot, it shows up as X2B and X3B. I assume this is because it thinks I want to do multiplication. How would I go about fixing this?

I tried changing the box in excel from general format to text.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I got this part figured out. So now I have:

```
baseball = read.csv(file="MultComp3.csv",row.names=1)
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(baseball)[1:16,1:16]
colnames(M) <- c("Age","Runs\nPer\nGame","Hits","Doubles","Triples",
                   "Home Runs","RBI","Stolen\nBases","Walks","Strike\nOuts",
                   "Batting\nAverage","On-Base\nPercentage","Slugging\nPercentage","OPS","OPS+","Total\nBases")
rownames(M) <- c("Age","Runs\nPer\nGame","Hits","Doubles","Triples",
                 "Home Runs","RBI","Stolen\nBases","Walks","Strike\nOuts",
                 "Batting\nAverage","On-Base\nPercentage","Slugging\nPercentage","OPS","OPS+","Total\nBases")
corrplot.mixed(M)
```

**EDIT 2:**

But now, I need to make the text smaller, because it comes out of the boxes.

[image]

Comment: `X` has nothing to do with multiplication. R does not like the name of a data frame begins with a number, so the `read.csv` function add `X` to `3B` and `2B`. You can change the names of those two columns before you do the corrplot.

Comment: I tried that but am having trouble doing so. I edited my question.

Comment: You may want to change the column name of your data frame directly. See the `names` or `colnames` function.

Comment: Got it working using colnames, thanks!